# Angular: Validators.email invalid if empty

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, validation

I'm creating an app in Angular (4.0), that contains a form (`FormGroup`).
In this form I have an email input (with `FormControl`), and I use `Validators.email` for validation.

```
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

// ...
let validators = [];
if ([condition]) {
    validators.push(Validators.email);
}
let fc = new FormControl([value] || '', validators);
// ...
```

But when the input is empty, it is invalid (it has an `ng-invalid` class), even if it's not required.

Is this a proper behavior? What can I do?

Comment: Take a look on this [**issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16183).

Comment: So there is no solution yet? Should I use Validators.pattern instead? @developer033

Comment: Yes, in this case it's better to use `Validatos.pattern` for now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**eric2783**'s solution is pretty good, however - if, in future, the output of `Validators.email` will change, then this custom validator will become not compatible with the angular's validator output.

Here's what you should do to keep the compatibility:

```
private customEmailValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
  if (!control.value) {
    return null;
  }

  return Validators.email(control);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The best solution that i found was this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.Email" [email]="model.Email!='' && model.Email!=null">
```

Comment: In angular 5 this creates a problem with the Angular lifecycle that it has been changed after it has been checked.

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish what you want with a custom validator. Here's the validator I wrote to get it to work:

```
private customEmailValidator(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    const emailError = Validators.email(control);
    if (control.value && emailError) {
        return {'email': {}};
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then you can replace `validators.push(Validators.email);` with `validators.push(this.customEmailValidator);`

It uses angular's built in email validator but also makes sure the email control has a value before returning an error.

Answer (score 5):

A Workaround in template-driven forms:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.email"  [email]="model.email!==''">
```

This worked for me (ensure to initialize the model value with an empty string).

Answer (score 4):

The shortest form to do this would be:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.email" [email]="!!model.email">
```